# A sufficient condition for a recurrent sequence to have a limit

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $a_{n+3}=\left\{ a_{n}\right\} +\left\{ a_{n+1}\right\} +\left\{
a_{n+2}\right\} ,$ $\forall n\geq 1.$ How to find $a_{1},$ $a_{2},$ $%
a_{3}\in \mathbb{Q}\cap \left( 0,1\right) $, such that the sequence $\left(
a_{n}\right) _{n\geq 1}$ has a limit? ($\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$).

Comment: Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true [...], it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts.  – From [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969).

Comment: Your comment does not help anymore. If you have a hint, you are welcome to post it and will be appreciated. I really don't know how to solve it.

Comment: It does help. It's about helping you to help us to help you. It's a lot easier for us to give you guidance if you tell us what you have tried. It lets us assess your level, which is important if we want to help you. The link given is from official site policy on how to ask good questions. It would be a good idea to actually follow it rather than claiming it doesn't help anyone. Also, not knowing where a finished solution starts is not the same as not knowing where to start looking for solutions. You must have tried at least one or two things before you came here to post this question, right?

Comment: No. It's a cool-looking problem. I want to help you through it. Heck, I want to solve it. But you have to meet us halfway there. So please, throw us a bone here.

Comment: If the sequence converges, it converges to $a$ such that

$$a=\{a\}+\{a\}+\{a\},$$ or

$$\lfloor a\rfloor= \{a\}+\{a\}$$ and $a=\dfrac32$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust How do you get $a=\{a\}+\{a\}+\{a\}$ knowing that $x \mapsto \{x\}$ is not continuous at integers?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: Mh, you are right. If $a_n$ tends to an integer, $\{a\}$ could be $0$ or ${1^-}$. Then solutions could be $0$ or $3$. Could they be $1$ or $2$ ?

Comment: If $\ a_1=a_2=a_3=\frac{1}{2}\ $, then $\ a_n=\frac{3}{2}\ $ for all $\ n\ge4\ $, so $\ \lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty}=\frac{3}{2}\ $ in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only possible values of $\ a_1,a_2,a_3\ $ for which the sequence will converge are $\ a_1=a_2=a_3=\frac{1}{2}\ $.

- As [Arthur](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/15500/arthur) observes in a comment on [mathcounterexamples.net's observations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4097768/a-sufficient-condition-for-a-recurrent-sequence-to-have-a-limit/4097817#4097817) the sequence can only converge if it's ultimately constant, and those observations show that the ultimate constant can only be $0,1,\frac{3}{2},$ or $2$.
- If the ultimate constant is an integer then since $\ a_{n+3}=\left\{a_n\right\}+\left\{a_{n+1}\right\}+\left\{a_{n+2}\right\}\ $, that integer can only be $0$, as [Yves Daoust](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/65203/yves-daoust) observes in a comment on mathcounterexamples.net's observations.
- If the limit were $0$, there would have to be a last integer $\ n\ $ for which $\ a_n\ne0\ $. Since $\ a_{n+3}=$$a_{n+2}=$$a_{n+1}=0\ $, $\ a_n\ $ must be an integer, as must $\ a_{n-1}\ $ and $\ a_{n-2}\ $. But then if $\ a_{n-3}\ $ were not an integer, then $\ a_n=\left\{a_{n-3}\right\}\ $ wouldn't be an integer either, and if $\ a_{n-3}\ $ *were* an integer, then $\ a_n\ $ would be $0$, which is a contradiction.  So the limit cannot be zero.
- Thus, the only possible limit is $\ \frac{3}{2}\ $. Again there must be a largest $\ n\ $ for which $\ a_n\ne\frac{3}{2}\ $.  The only possible values for $\ a_n\ $ are then $\ \frac{1}{2}\ $ or $\ \frac{5}{2}\ $ and the only possible values for $\ a_{n-1}\ $ and $\ a_{n-2}\ $ are $\ \frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\ $ or $\ \frac{5}{2}\ $. But then $\ \left\{a_{n-3}\right\}+\left\{a_{n-2}\right\}+\left\{a_{n-1}\right\}=\left\{a_{n-3}\right\}+1<2\ $, so $\ a_n\ $ cannot be $\ \frac{5}{2}\ $, so must be $\ \frac{1}{2}\ $. But if $\ n>3\ $ then $ a_n=\left\{a_{n-3}\right\}+\left\{a_{n-2}\right\}+\left\{a_{n-1}\right\}=\left\{a_{n-3}\right\}+1>1\ $ so we must have $\ n\le3\ $.  Since $\ a_{n+1}=\frac{3}{2}>1\ $, however, we must have $\ n=3\ $. And, since $\ a_{n-1}=a_2<1\ $ and $\ a_{n-2}=a_1<1\ $ we must have $\ a_1=a_2=a_3=\frac{1}{2}\ $.

Comment: lonza leggiera, mathcounterexamples.net, Yves Daoust Thank you for this elegant solution!

Answer (score 3):

**Not a solution... just basic thoughts**

Suppose that $\{a_n\}$ has a limit $l$. As the sequence takes values in $[0,3)$, $l \in [0,3]$.

As $x \mapsto \{x\}$ is continuous on $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Z$ if $l \notin \mathbb Z$ we must have $l=3\{l\}$. The only non integer solution is $3/2$.

If $l \in \mathbb Z$ then $l \in \{0,1,2,3\}$. Hence, $l$ has to belong to $\{0, 3/2, 1, 2, 3\}$.

And I have made no use of the hypothesis

$$H \equiv a_1, a_2, a_3 \in \mathbb Q \cap (0,1).$$

Comment: How can $\frac23$ be a solution ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust A typo, I meant $3/2$. "Answer" updated.

Comment: The only integer solution is $l=0$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust How do you conclude that?

Comment: What do you think of $3\{l\}$ when $l\in\mathbb N$ ??

Comment: It's zero. But as $x \mapsto \{x\}$ is not continuous at the integers, the equation $a=3\{a\}$ may not hold at those points.

Comment: Using the hypothesis $H$ means the sequence can only converge iff it's constant; the common denominator across three consecutive terms can never grow above the common denominator of $a_1, a_2, a_3$.